# Installing Wine with MacPorts

Tags: wine, macports

I'm using a MacBook Pro Snow leopard and trying to install wine in the terminal.

I enter: `sudo ports install wine`
and I get: `sudo: ports: command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the command is `port`, not `ports`.

Comment: Beat me by 3 seconds... grrrrr `;)`

Comment: @Jess: If this answer worked for you, please click the green checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted.